# How do I theme a blog listing page for a specific taxonomy term?

Tags: theming

I have a site, where a blog listing of a particular category, say Resources, has to have the "Read More" button say "Download Resource" instead.

I saw that this is controlled by a template file called 'node--blog-tpl.php' in the theme, with the following code:

```
    <?php if($extended == '1'): ?>
        <a class="btn readmore" href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print t('Read More');?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Since I wanted to change this just for the 'Resources' category, which was Taxonomy Term 23 for me, I copied this file and renamed it all manner of combinations/permutations of filenames with 'taxonomy--term-23' in it, but nothing seems to work.

Can someone please help me with this? I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance,
Jasper

Answer (score 0):

Blog list pages render node teasers. I think that the automatic template suggestion patterns would only operate on node attributes and taxonomy is not one.

You can add this to your theme's `template.php` file

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // check for blog and teaser
  if ($variables['type'] == 'blog' && $variables['view_mode'] == "teaser") {
     // check for taxonomy term on node
     dpm($variables);
     if ($variables['field_TAXONOMYFIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'] == TAXONOMYID) {
       // change the readmore link here or add code for template file
       $variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title'] = "Custom Read Me";
     }
  }
}
```

If you don't want to override the readmore link inside the preprocess function but absolutely want a template file, then you can instead do this:

```
array_unshift($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'], "node__blog__blahblah");
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried this in the template.php file but it did not work. Maybe some of the variables are not the same - like view_mode or TAXONOMYFIELD. Not sure of how to implement the 'theme_hook_suggestions' solution, otherwise I would have tried that as well. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes those are only place holders for you to add your values to. TAXONOMYID was 23 for you. Install [Deve](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)l module then put in dpm statement as per my aupdated answer. You can then inspect for your field values etc. Also note THEME is a placeholder that you need to replace with your own.